# Jquery - Forms Plugin, Dynamic Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using JQuery UI tabs. When i create a tab using the "$("#" + target).tabs('add', url, title);" method it opens a tab and calls an ajax form correctly..

Now the problem exists when i open an identical tab containing the identical form. When the form is submitted using the forms plugin, things mess up. I am presuming this is due to multiple areas having the same div id and so the form plugin does not know which to update..

Is there a work around for this at all ??

Answer (score 0):

I share your suspicion that this is caused by multiple elements having identical `id` values (which is invalid html).  You can resolve this by modifying the value of the `id` attribute using jQuery's `attr` function.